# event.preventDefault not working when validating radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, preventdefault

I am trying to validate if all items (radio buttons) are checked. The following code works, but as soon as I click on the alert-window, it pops up again. Using `event.stopPropagation()` doesn't change anything. It is not waiting for the user to check the remaining items.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('submit','#formular',function(event){
            $("input:radio").each(function() {
                var val = $('input:radio[name=' + this.name + ']:checked').val();
                if (val === undefined) {
                    alert("Not every item answered");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Can't really comprehend the problem here! please post a fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't quit a loop using `preventDefault`, normally you would use `break` or `continue`, but on a jQuery `$.each` you must use `return true` to continue and `return false` equivalent to `break`.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('submit','#formular',function(event){
            $("input:radio").each(function() {
                var val = $('input:radio[name=' + this.name + ']:checked').val();
                if (val === undefined) {
                    alert("Not every item answered");
                    return false;
                }
            });
            // When invalid formular:
            return false;
            // When it's valid:
            return true;
        });
    });
```

See also this question: [jquery validation: prevent form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305938/jquery-validation-prevent-form-submit)

See:

[How to break out of jQuery each Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784780/how-to-break-out-of-jquerys-each-loop)

[How to break/exit from a each() function in JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799284/how-to-break-exit-from-a-each-function-in-jquery)

https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: thanks, but when i use `return = false;` instead, it immediately loads the next page.

Comment: how do I check if the formular is valid or not?

Comment: There are many ways to do that. My fav and the most reliable is to send all the data via Ajax to the server, let the server validate the data and return JSON with either success true or success false + error message.

Comment: ok, but if I only want to use jquery. How do I have to change the function above to achieve this?

Comment: You set a variable `isValid = true;` and when one field does not fit the requirements, you set `isValid = false` at the end you simply return this variable to abort or continue to submit. But keep in mind: client side validation is not reliable. Anyone can bypass Javascript and send wrong stuff to your server.