# Prevent form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, validation

I would like to set a js var to true but **ONLY if the login data is correct, NOT IF the form is valid(fields empty .. )** how can i do that? I'm using the jQuery validation plugin and i modified the submitHandler, so that the form is only submitting, if flag is true.

```
var flag = false;

$('#login-form').validate(
{
    rules:
    {
        User: "required",
        Password: "required"
    },
    messages:
    {
        User: "Please enter a Username!<br />",
        Password: "Please enter a Password!",
    },
    submitHandler: function(form)
    {
        if(flag)
        {
            var message = document.createElement("div");
            message.id = "info";
            message.style.width = "250px";
            message.style.height = "25px";
            message.style.color = "green";
            message.innerHTML = '<p style="text-align: center;">Your Login Data is correct!.</p>';

            $("#login-form").after(message);
            form.submit();
        }
    },
});
```

Here's php part, where i would like to set flag to true, if the login data is correct, else it should stay as it is but how can i set flag now?

```
if(!empty($result))
{        
    **Here i want to set the Flag!!
    $flag = true; ??****

    $_SESSION["loggedin"] = $user;
    header ("Location: index.php?site=backend"); 
    exit;
}
else
{
    echo '<p style="text-align: center; color: red">The username or password is wrong!</p>';
    header ("Refresh:2; url=index.php?site=backend-login"); 
    exit;
}
```

or is there any better way to do it? I just would like to not always have the form reloaded, because it's a self-submitting form. After that i would also like to show an information message.
**So, how can i set or change the existing value of var test?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery validation: prevent form submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305938/jquery-validation-prevent-form-submit)

Comment: Please check this

http://www.websitecodetutorials.com/code/jquery-plugins/jquery-validation.php

Comment: that's not what i want. I explained it a bit more detailed above now.

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
var flag = $('#login-form').valid();
```

.. you will get the boolean value in `flag`.

---

Read up: [`.valid()` | jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)

---

PS. It is better to use HTML element in the jQuery selector so it works faster.

```
form#login-form
```

---

**EDIT:**

Working code snippet:

```js
var flag = false;

$('#login-form').validate(
  {
    rules:
    {
      User: "required",
      Password: "required"
    },
    messages:
    {
      User: "Please enter a Username!<br />",
      Password: "Please enter a Password!",
    },
    submitHandler: function(form)
    {
      var flag = $('#login-form').valid();
      if(flag)
      {
        var message = document.createElement("div");
        message.id = "info";
        message.style.width = "250px";
        message.style.height = "25px";
        message.style.color = "green";
        message.innerHTML = '<p style="text-align: center;">Your Login Data is correct!.</p>';

        $("#login-form").after(message);
        form.submit();
      }
    },
  });
```

```css
input, label{
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

label.error{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="login-form">
  <input type="text" id="User" name="User" />
  <input type="password" id="Password" name="Password" />
  <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>
```

**EDIT 2:**

In response to the comments, I highly recommend using AJAX for this. With AJAX, first check if the user exists and then set appropriate value to `flag` and pass it to Javascript and then go ahead with it.

Read up: [`jQuery.ajax()` | jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

This is the most appropriate way of passing data from JS to PHP and the other way round.

Comment: That's not what i want. If i do that my form is valid, when the fields are not empty, but i would like to set the flag, when my login data is correct. I would also like to change the value in php, like shown above.

Comment: @Procos That is incorrect. The form doesnt get submitted if you have those rules and use my line of code. Please check the EDIT in my answer above, it has a working demo of the same. And I dont really understand why you need to set the flag in PHP if you can do it in Javascript. Keep it simple. :)

Comment: It seems like you don't understand what i mean. The form validation itself already worked but i would like to ONLY submit the form, if a user is found and if the login is successfull. I would like to set the flag to true then and only then. I've want to to set it in the if(!empty($result)) case

Comment: @Procos Please see EDIT 2 in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP file you ll need to output some javascript code like this

```
// PHP file where your checks are making flag = true
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var flag = true; </script>';
```

and

```
// PHP file where your checks are making flag = false
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> var flag = false; </script>';
```

then DO NOT re-assign value to your flag with your javascript. remove the `var flag = false;` from your javascript.

Be careful, the PHP must echo BEFORE your js code (so your flag will take a value first then your js will work with it).

Comment: i believe this is a mistake