# in jquery validation the error message disappears quickly

Tags: jquery, html

I have tried by using the below code but the error message disappears quickly

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').submit(function () {
        if ($("#first").val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$')) {
            alert("valid");
        } else {
            $("#error_msg").after("invalid");
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: try adding event.preventDefault(); in else

Comment: can anyone help me how to show the error message from disappearing quickly

Comment: What do you mean by "disappearing quickly"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery validation: prevent form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305938/jquery-validation-prevent-form-submit)

Comment: @Sujith but my error message continuously printing

Comment: @tamil check my answer.You Can  empty or remove the text and then append the text invalid.So it wont continuously print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event.preventDefault().If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').submit(function(event) {
    if ($("#first").val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$')) {
      alert("valid");
    } else {
       $("#error_msg").empty().text("invalid");
       alert("invalid");
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" id="first">
<div id="error_msg"></div>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks sujith tahnks for your expalanation i got an answer

Answer (score 1):

Use `preventDefault()` method to stop the default action of an element from happening:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    if($("#first").val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$')){
       alert("valid");
    }
    else{
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#error_msg").after("invalid");
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: but if i try to click submit again error message(invalid) is showing continuously like invalidinvalidinvalid

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false;`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    if($("#first").val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$')){
       alert("valid");
    }
    else{      
      $("#error_msg").after("invalid");
       return false;
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: @tamil Have u got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false` or `preventDefault()` method to stop the action :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(e){
    if($("#first").val().match('^[a-zA-Z]{3,16}$')){
       alert("valid");
    }
    else{
      $("#error_msg").after("invalid");
      return false;
      //or
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  })
})
```